# Why empty class object's property is not giving error on access of property?

Tags: php, oop

I was reading about php __get and __set magic methods and as per my understanding it is useful to access undefined or private property of class.
So i was trying to access undefined property of class to check what error it is throwing. But in place of error it gives value i have assigned to property on object.
see below code.

```
class test{
}
$obj = new test();
$obj->name = "Hello";
echo $obj->name;
```

Output is "Hello".

I am not getting why is it not throwing any error ? 
What is use of __get for undefined variable ?? 
Why it is giving "Hello" as output?

Comment: It is _not_ undefined, because you explicitly _assigned_ a value to it on the previous line, which automatically “created” it.

Comment: Oh okay . If i explicitly assigned a value so i am able to access directly but than what will be the use of __get and  __set for undefined property.

Comment: If you implement your own magic setter method, then in there you could for example decide _which_ properties you want to allow to be created this way … like only ones starting with a certain prefix, and all others would be rejected. And a magic getter could for example return a default value for properties that don’t exist (yet) …

Comment: Hmm. I am confused . It will be great if you can give an example.

Comment: Not really the purpose of this site … Suggest you go find yourself a book or some tutorials on the matter.

Comment: It's pretty simple: `__get` will be invoked if you try to *read* a property that doesn't exist. `__set` will be invoked if you try to *assign* to a property that doesn't exist. Without `__set`, `$obj->name = ...` simply creates the property `name`, henceforth it *does* exist, and you can simply access it.